# C# Start from search programs

Tags: c#

How can I execute a search as if it was the search programs and files box in the start menu?
I want to start an application with a partial word search.

To be more specific.

If I put in the word skype.
I want skype to run.

Normally I can do this by entering the word into the search bar in the start menu and pressing enter. But I want to do this though some less obvious means.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Please be more specific in your question. What exactly are you trying to do? Give an example.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you could try opening an exporer with this string `search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results&crumb=$$$$SEARCHSTRING$$$$`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx to open an explorer.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [Windows API Code Pack](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack). It makes it much easier to integrate a managed application with Window 7/Vista.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to launch an external program from your own C# program, you can do this:

```
Process launchProcess = new Process(); 
launchProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "Notepad.exe"; 
launchProcess.Start();
```

Comment: Sure, but this is not what I'm looking for. I need a way to locate where the apps are, like "search" does.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple links that get you started on using Windows Search:

- Windows Search Overview http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362.aspx,
- Using Managed Code with Shell Data and Windows Search http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb286799.aspx
- Use Windows Vista Search API from a WPF Application http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/Vista_Search_in_WPF.aspx.